# Convert Wordpress Twenty Ten theme to bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on converting Wordpress Twenty Ten theme to Bootstrap

Here is the code in index.php

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(200,160), array("class" => "img-responsive img-thumbnail home-thumb")); } ?></a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .col-md-9-->
```

But empty space is displayed if we don't have an image in our post.

Here is the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfr8y.jpg

How to use 'col-md-12' instead of 'col-md-9' if we don't have thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(200,160), array("class" => "img-responsive img-thumbnail home-thumb")); } ?></a>
 </div>

<div class="<?php echo (has_post_thumbnail())?'col-md-9':'col-md-12'?>">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .col-md-9--
```